# Oracle DB User alias

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, alias

Is there a SQL script I could run, or some other action I could take, that would create an alias for an entire DB User? I'm running in to an issue where the User name text is too long for a particular program, and I want to create an alias or nickname for that UserId.

Edits:

Rather than logging in with UserId: , Password , I want to log in with UserId: , Password.

The program is not under my control beyond chaning the oracle User ID / Password login credentials.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to alias all user objects so you won't have to use: <longUserName>.<objectName> ?

Comment: I want to log in with a differnet UserId entirely, if that is possible. I added specifics in post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an alias for a database user, no.

Perhaps you don't need to, though.  If A (the user with the long name) owns a number of objects, you can create a new database user B with a short name, grant B privileges on the objects in A, and then change the `current_schema` when B logs in so that references to objects are resolved using A's schema

```
ALTER SESSION
  SET current_schema = A;
```

That should accomplish most of what the alias would provide.

Comment: That's a good idea. Unfortunately, the application managing the oracle connections is limited to me changing the userid / password, so it won't work in my particular case. This is a good answer though.

Comment: @StealthRabbi - You can always create a login trigger in schema B that runs the `ALTER SESSION` to set the `current_schema` to A.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use a proxy user that can connect to the DB on behalf of the longNamed user:
[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:21575905259251](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3ap11_question_id:21575905259251)

Actually, if it's only for login purpose then maybe you can use [Secure External Password Store](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/SecureExternalPasswordStore_10gR2.php)
 and avoid putting any username/password